# C++ implementation in header issues

Tags: c++, compilation, header-files

I'm working on a fairly large project (3D graphics engine) and I've run into some trouble while restructuring the code a bit. I want to have all of my classes implemented in single files (only have .hpp rather than having both a .cpp and .hpp file for each class). I don't have a specific reason for doing it this way other than just wanting to, but I'm hoping to avoid discussions over what C++ best practices are.

When I do it this way I get a series of multiple definition errors that look like this:

```
/tmp/ccztDQam.o: In function `Point3DH::normalize()':
Renderer.cpp:(.text+0x736): multiple definition of `Point3DH::normalize()'
/tmp/ccawpiuU.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1a6de): first defined here
/tmp/ccztDQam.o: In function `Point3DH::dot(Point3DH, Point3DH)':
Renderer.cpp:(.text+0x79e): multiple definition of `Point3DH::dot(Point3DH, Point3DH)'
/tmp/ccawpiuU.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1a746): first defined here
/tmp/ccztDQam.o: In function `Point3DH::cross(Point3DH, Point3DH)':
Renderer.cpp:(.text+0x7d6): multiple definition of `Point3DH::cross(Point3DH, Point3DH)'
/tmp/ccawpiuU.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1a77e): first defined here
...
```

The issue comes when the classes start including each other and code is repeated multiple times. It seems that header guards are not sufficient as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8108125/4753200) answer. I'm wondering if there is any way to get around this or an alternate way to achieve the goal.

The project is organized into modules (folders) such as geometry or polygon which contain relevant classes so include paths go to the parent directory and then into the correct module and class

For reference, here is what one of the files looks like (./graphics/Raster.hpp):

```
#ifndef GRAPHICS_RASTER
#define GRAPHICS_RASTER

#include "../graphics/Colour.hpp"
#include <vector>

class Raster {
private:
    std::vector<Colour> image;
    std::vector<double> zBuffer;
    int width;
    int height;
public:
    Raster(int, int, Colour);
    void setPixel(int, int, double, Colour);
    int getWidth();
    int getHeight();
};

#endif

#ifndef GRAPHICS_RASTER_IMPLEMENTATION
#define GRAPHICS_RASTER_IMPLEMENTATION

#include "../graphics/Colour.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

Raster::Raster(int width, int height, Colour clear) :
    image(std::vector<Colour>(width*height, clear)),
    zBuffer(std::vector<double>(width*height, -std::numeric_limits<double>::max())),
    width(width),
    height(height)
{}

void Raster::setPixel(int x, int y, double z, Colour c) {
    if(x < 0 || x >= width || y < 0 || y >= height) return;
    if(z <= zBuffer[(height - y - 1)*width + x]) return;
    image[(height - y - 1)*width + x] = c;
    zBuffer[(height - y - 1)*width + x] = z;
}

int Raster::getWidth()  {return  width;}
int Raster::getHeight() {return height;}

#endif
```

Comment: "I don't have a specific reason for doing it this way other than just wanting to, but I'm hoping to avoid discussions over what C++ best practices are." still, keep in mind that this will be an obvious optimization spot the moment you'll want to have a potentially faster and more parallel build.

Comment: I know what works, but I don't want to do it. I want to do something different even though I can already see it's causing me difficulty. Don't tell me about all the other the things that can go wrong. I'm not going to explain why I'm choosing to make things unnecessarily complicated. I just want you to fix the the problem I have deliberately created for myself. Why: because I WANT IT!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you for some reason want to implement everything in header files, you have to make all your functions inline. Functions defined in class definitions are implicitly inline. Functions defined out-of-class have to be declared with `inline` keyword explicitly.

That's what you have to do with every definition that you have in the "implementation" section of your header - add explicit `inline` keyword to every function definition. E.g.

```
inline void Raster::setPixel(int x, int y, double z, Colour c) { 
    if(x < 0 || x >= width || y < 0 || y >= height) return; 
    if(z <= zBuffer[(height - y - 1)*width + x]) return; 
    image[(height - y - 1)*width + x] = c; 
    zBuffer[(height - y - 1)*width + x] = z; 
}
```

and so on.

Of course, you can also move all your member function definitions into class definition (which will make them inline), but that will preclude such distinctly separated two-section header structure as you have now. I don't know how important it is to you.

Comment: This works and allows me to compile and run the code, but what is the effect of doing this? Is the same as if I had written the code inline in the class definition, or is the compiler trying to inline the code in every location it is called?

Comment: @Chuck: Modern compilers typically use their own heuristic critera when they decide whether to inline a function call or not. Which means that the abobe explicit `inline` might have no effect on inlining at all - the compiler's own decisions will "override" it anyway. So, the only definitive effect it has is that it allows you to make multiple definitions of the same function in different translation units without triggering the linker error.

Comment: The linker is this case will have to quetly remove excessive definitions, leaving only one. Producing these numerous identical definitions only to be discarded later is extra wasted effort for compiler and linker. This will typically result in compilation taking longer than before (i.e. as opposed to "classic" approach where functions are defined only once in one of implementation files). But that's expected price to pay for having everyhting defined in header files.

Comment: @Chuck Why are you now asking "what is the effect of doing this"? Your question stated that your were "hoping to avoid discussions over what C++ best practices are". _I suggest you do some research in how to improve compile times in C++_.  Maybe you'll rethink this _not-so novel_ idea of yours.

Comment: @CraigYoung I'm not really too worried about compile times, just want to make sure there is no impact on run times. The entire program is only a few thousand lines so it compiles pretty quickly either way. The main reason for doing this was that most of the classes were around 100 lines of code so it is an editing convenience to have everything in one file.

Answer (score 2):

Every time your header is included in a cpp file, you create a new copy of the implementation.

You need to make sure that the implementation is only used in one cpp file - or inline every method.

Answer (score 1):

This guide have good ideas on doing that:

https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/docs/stb_howto.txt

examples:

https://github.com/nothings/stb

Basically:

1-make a **#define UNIQUE_NAME_IMP** and **#define UNIQUE_NAME_HEADER** to make implementation and declaration visible on different files by using:

your implementation:

```
#ifdef _DECL_
 type declaration
 function prototype
#endif

#ifdef _IMPL_
 code
#endif
```

and in another file that will use it:

```
#define _DECL_
#include <my_header.h>
code...
...
//use this only once to avoid 
//duplicate symbol like you mentioned in your post.
#define _IMPL_
#include <my_header.h>
```

2-avoid memory allocation, make your functions use the memory you pass on with your structures.

3-avoid external dependencies. Each dependency will make you use flags or create requirements to comply before using your header...

4-use "static". This makes the implementation private to the source file that creates it.

Comment: I think I'll do something similar to this. It was actually from looking at the source code of the stb library that sent me on this wild crusade to combine all of my files like this.